# How do I delete pip and python

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pip

I've been having a lot of trouble with python and pip, I think both got corrupted or something. I'm new to all this. I'm using a Macbook pro running Monterey and I was curious how to delete python and pip so I can re-install them. Any ideas are greatly appreciated. I have it all installed in the terminal, no applications I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed the earlier version of Python, you can take this method to uninstall it from your Mac. First open the Terminal, and input the following command lines:

```
sudo rm -rf “/Applications/Python”
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/python
```

In order to delete pip you can use the following command

```
sudo python -m pip uninstall pip
```

or

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove python3-pip
```

I hope that my answer will be useful.

Comment: Thank you, I'm fairly sure this works. Checking right now.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using mac you can type into terminal the following command to get the path of python and pip:

Python:

```sh
python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
```

Pip:

```
which pip
```

Just use `rm -r` followed by the path you got